# Stackoverflow exception during maven package

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-3, sonatype

Need your help in fixing the maven compilation issue. I am not able to run any maven commands on my project. I am getting the following exception.  Maven version used is

```
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_09, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Maven Command Used

```
mvn -o package and mvn package
```

Exception Stacktrace :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.visitEnter(PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.java:88)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:198)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
```

Please give some idea to fix this issue.

Comment: +1 for asking a question on Stack Overflow about a literal stackoverflow.

Comment: A stack overflow error often indicates a recursion or circular dependency problem.  Look at the POMs, and verify that you don't have two (or more) projects that depend on each other.  E.g., project A has B as a dependency, while B lists A as a dependency.

Comment: @user944849 - Nope, there are no such dependencies that can create a cyclic problem. And the interesting fact is that the same project builds fine in a jenkin build. But its not working in my local set-up. Any other settings i need to look for ?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat :- That's a nice catch. Let see whether a real stackoverflow problem can be fixed with the help of Stack OverFlow.

Comment: That is helpful information.  I would compare the {user.home}/.m2/settings.xml for the user Jenkins runs as with your local settings.xml.  What are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug of Maven 3.0.4.

Upgrade to [Maven 3.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) resolved that for me.